# Can I call the very top constructor for a child class in a long inheritance chain?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

Here is my chain:

```
public abstract class Item ->
  public abstract class MiscItem ->
    public abstract class OtherItem ->
       public class TransformableOther;
```

In `Item`, there's a copy constructor:

```
public Item (Item other)
{
 // copy stuff ...
}
```

And I want to do this:

```
var trans = new TransformableOther (otherItem);
```

Of course that didn't work, I went to `TransformableOther` and tried:

```
public TransformableOther(Item other): base (other) {}
```

But that didn't work as well, of course that's just calling the parent that's directly above. I went there, to `OtherItem` and did the same, and so for its parent `MiscItem`,
it didn't work.

How can I achieve what I want? - And if I can't, what's the hack around this?

Thanks.

EDIT: My bad, for some reason in my code I was doing `base.Item(otherItem)` and not `base(otherItem)` which is actually what I wrote in the question.

Comment: it worked just fine for me, can you share your code?

Comment: How is public Item(Item other) implemented? Are you performing deep or shallow copies?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: 'what' worked for you?

Thanatos: Deep copy I believe, copying the fields that I care about.

Comment: @VeXe i did just like Panu Horsmalahti and it worked

Comment: Yes, thanks and sorry. For some reason I was doing base.Item(other) and not base (other) which is actually what I wrote in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
public abstract class Item
{
    private Item other;
    public Item(Item item)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Creating Item!");
        other = item;
    }

    public abstract class MiscItem : Item
    {
        public MiscItem(Item item) : base(item)
        {

        }

        public abstract class OtherItem : MiscItem
        {
            public OtherItem(Item item) : base(item)
            {

            }

            public class TransformableOther : OtherItem
            {
                public TransformableOther() : base(null)
                {

                }

                public TransformableOther(Item item) : base(item)
                {

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can test it with

```
         Item.MiscItem.OtherItem.TransformableOther other = new Item.MiscItem.OtherItem.TransformableOther();
        var item = new Item.MiscItem.OtherItem.TransformableOther(other);
```

Comment: Don't nest the classes like this. It's weird and confusing, and violates the guideline that nested classes should always be private. Maybe you thought that's what the OP was signifying with his `->` chain, but I'm pretty sure it's just the usual inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

In C# there is no way to do what you're asking for. Essentially you can only call the constructors of the the class you directly inherit from.

If you have control over the implementation of `Item` then I think the best work around would be to use a virtual Clone/Copy method instead of a copy constructor, that way you can override that method even if `MiscItem` and `OtherItem` don't provide their own implementations.

Comment: Yes, first thing came to mind was to make a Copy method, but it seems that I can do what I originally wanted as well. Check answer ^

Comment: @VeXe you're still only calling the constructor of `OtherItem`. Implementing so many constructors just to pass it on to a class down the inheritance line seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Hmm, it seems tedious yes. I ended up using a Copy method, but then found another approach to the problem I had in hand without copying anything :) - For this problem, I think your approach is better, but I marked the ^ answer correct because it answered the question directly, it's nice to know how constructors are chained and how you would call parents. thanks.